# add widgets to dashboard for easy access for clients?

Tags: widgets, dashboard

I have a widget created:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
  register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Featured Video',
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget' => '',
    'before_title' => '',
    'after_title' => '',
  ));
```

All is good, I was just wondering if it was possible to show this widget on the dashboard so the client can easily change the contents when needed. I just want my client to have easier access to it. If it's not possible, no big deal.

Comment: [It is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14904308/1287812), but **not easy at all**...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to trust my gut can agree with brasofilo.

As a work around, why not just create a custom post type and then have the widget pull content from that instead of the widget's instance? You can make it so the widget accepts a post ID #  and only pulls from that ID for that widget's instance.